# Invoke Sync with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

Normally, I integrate the deployment source to webapp, and then **run the 'Sync'** button found in the webapp dashboard as and when required to sync the Azure webapp with my onedrive folder.

But, if I want to give a *non-Azure user*, I mean , who need **not be logged in to Azure portal** itself, rather could invoke with a demo credential or sort, what should I do? Or, If I want to run it myself from shell, how to approach?

**Would it be possible to run the sync from power-shell** with service principal or similar ways ( runbooks, http trigger with azure functions for sync ) without actually giving the user a login credential itself?

Update: 
1. I read this blog on Kudu but not sure whether it is what I am actually looking for. Please suggest. https://dzimchuk.net/post/azure-web-apps-continuous-deployment

**Update 31/Aug**:

My workflow got 3 slots dev/stage/mirror. I aim to integrate dev with source repo. So, Sync is enabled at lowest environment.

```
SiteName                  : YourWebApp(dev)
State                     : Running
DefaultHostName           : YourWebApp-dev.azurewebsites.net
Id                        : /subscriptions/1234567890-{my}-{subscription}_{id}/resourceGroups/Default-Web/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/YourWebApp/slots/dev
Name                      : YourWebApp/dev
Location                  : East US
Type                      : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots
```

Comment: Sorry! Being a PHP guy, it takes a double confirmation route even to step to explore in Microsoft terrain. That's the reason to post and might be another guy like me find this helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the latest Azure PowerShell, you can run this command to trigger a sync:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName {YourResourceGroup} -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceName YourWebApp -Action sync -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Or if you're dealing with a slot, it will look like this:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName {YourResourceGroup} -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName YourWebApp/YourSlot -Action sync -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

As far as letting some other user authenticate, you have a couple options:

1. You can make them a Contributor on that Web App (using RBAC - Role Based Access Control)
2. You can set up a [Service Principal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/)

Comment: Thanks for sync trigger from cmdlet. On user authentication,  I have tried the service principal setup before to have non-interactive login, but as I recollect, I had challenge of write access or sort. Admin IT is still on that ticket as I am having co-admin role but not authorized to give access to AD. let me try your pointer and be back. Might be I missed something in setup.

Comment: Regarding sync cmdlet, works well for no slots app. In my case, used mentioned cmdlet above with -ResourceName as 1) [ YourWebApp/dev ] , 2) [ YourWebApp/slots/dev ]  . 1) and 2) gets the command look at mirror slot ( Repository does not exist for site 
YourWebApp ) and finds no repo existing, which is true.

Comment: Also tried with and [ YourWebApp`(dev`) ] But gives ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/YourWebApp(dev)' under resource group 'Default-Web' was not found. Please find the update to main thread on slot am trying to trigger sync.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a ton! (bow)